# Map tests in jasmine 'throw [object ErrorEvent] thrown' error

Tags: angular, types, jasmine, maps

I have map code, within a subscribe, in typescript and now i am getting a 'throw [object ErrorEvent] thrown' error message from my tests. If i run the tests individually they work, its only when i run 2 of them together that i get the error message. I have seen other posts where it says to run the tests using this command - ng test --source-map=false (my version of cli is over v6.0.8), but i still get the same error message.

```js
public show(user: UserModel): void {
        this.getRoles(user.id)
            .subscribe(
                roles => {
                    this.availableRoles.map(pubRoles => {
                        if (pubRoles.name.includes("test")) {
                            this.showState = true;
                        }
                    });
                    this.visible = true;
                }
            );
}
```

```js
describe('show tests', () => {
        it('should testroleData', () => {
            component.show(userData[1]);
            expect(component.roles[0]).toBe(roleData);
        });

        it('should set the visible boolean to true', () => {
            component.show(userData[1]);
            expect(component.visible).toBe(true);
        });
});
```

Also, in the . map code if i change this line - if (pubRoles.name.includes("test")) - to if (pubRoles[0].name.includes("test")) - the tests work.

Comment: Look at your browser console, which should display the error in full.

Comment: The console says - "TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined". This is related to the line - pubRoles.name.includes("test"). And if i change this to pubRoles[0].name.includes("test"), the test works. But the code itself works so didn't think i needed to update it. Also, if i run the tests individually (using fit), they work

Comment: Please spot the code of your mocked service.